# copy (clone) a file into same dired buffer

Tags: dired

Im looking for a way to copy (clone) a file into same dired buffer.

For example if i have a `test.zip` file in `~` i would issue it and it would copy `test.zip` file to `~`. a bonus would be if one can assign a number/string to the new cloned file like `test1.zip`

Comment: Something I've written some time ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17428952/dired-duplicate-files-the-operation-not-how-to-get-rid-of-em may not be 100% your case, but close.

Comment: [`dired-do-copy`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Operating-on-Files.html)?